# Issue in hiding youtube player info and suggested list in iOS

Tags: swift, youtubeplayer

i have used YTPlayerView in my VC where i load the songs through song VideoId,Now when the song run in player it shows me info, share, Song logo and name and when pause the video it shows related songs list. I'm trying to hide all of this from player for that i have search and applied the results but it isn't working. This is my code,

```
let playerVars = [ "modestbranding": 1,
                   "rel" : 0,
                   "fs" : 1,
                   "playsinline" : 1,
                   "origin" : "https://www.youtube.com",
                   "showinfo" : 0] as [String : Any]
self.songView.load(withVideoId: videoId, playerVars: playerVars)
```

But when i run the code it again shows me these stuffs,
[image]
How i can remove all of these just want to show song video?

Comment: Unfortunately showinfo flag is deprecated and ignored after 25-9-2018 https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo

Comment: So, now what to do how i can hide them? @MoayadAlkouz

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do anything

Comment: The how i can remove the below list for suggested videos this isn't deprecated yet? @MoayadAlkouz

Comment: Also you can't hide suggested videos

Comment: can we just give userInteraction false at these stuff? @MoayadAlkouz